# What is the special name for linear regression when there are many parameters in y instead of one?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

I rememeber reading about something that is exactly a linear regression  A x = y

Except that y for each x, is not just one point but rather a vector.

Can any one please remind me what's that?

Comment: You're using the term *parameter* for what statisticians would normally say *variable*. The word *parameter* means something quite different to us https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter - this may lead to some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than one response variable is known as **multivariate regression**.

More than one predictor variable is known as **multiple regression** (compared to simple regression for a single variable).